# How to rename a command for a symbol

Tags: macros, symbols

I'm using the symbol `int` for the interior of the topological space and `Int` for the interior of a closed manifold in R<sup>n</sup>.

But `\int` is the built-in command for the 'integral' symbol. How can I rename the integral symbol to `\intgrl`?

At this moment, I have:

```
\def\int{\mathrm{int}}
\def\Int{\mathrm{Int}}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you probably need to use something like:

```
\let\intgrl\int
\def\int{\mathrm{int}}
\def\Int{\mathrm{Int}}
```

Answer (score 16):

Don't use `\mathrm` for defining operators: the spacing might be wrong. Compare

```
\[ \mathrm{int} A \]
```

versus

```
\[ \mathop{\mathrm{int}} A \]
```

There's no need to use the complicated second construction, because `amsmath` provides an easy way to get it.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\intgrl\int % keep the original definition of `\int`
\let\int\relax % to avoid a "spurious" error message
\DeclareMathOperator{\int}{int}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Int}{Int}
```

However, I wouldn't redefine `\int` and use

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\sint}{int}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sInt}{Int}
```

("s" for "set").

Answer (score 2):

In one of the source files for [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) by Scott Pakin there is this

```
% There are a number of symbols (e.g., \Square) that are defined by      %
% multiple packages.  In order to typeset all the variants in this       %
% document, we have to give glyph a unique name.  To do that, we define  %
% \savesymbol{XXX}, which renames a symbol from \XXX to \origXXX, and    %
% \restoresymbols{yyy}{XXX}, which renames \origXXX back to \XXX and     %
% defines a new command, \yyyXXX, which corresponds to the most recently %
% loaded version of \XXX.                                                %
```

Somewhere else he mentions that the commands are avialable in the [`savesym`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/savesym) package (though that didn't seem to have any docmentation, hence the above copy past). I could get the package through miktex package manager.

Check out the file [symbols.tex](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/source/symbols.tex) for more info (he re-implements the commands).